# Search classes in an assembly and call a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to find all classes in an assembly that impelement certain interface and then basically get a property of that object in my view.  Here is what I have tried:

```
List<IManager> Managers = new List<IManager>();
const string @namespace = "MyProject.Models.Manager";
var managerClasses = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace
        select t;

foreach (var managerClass in managerClasses.Where(t => typeof(IManager).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
{
    var r = (IManager) managerClass;
    Managers.Add(r);
}
```

My code crashes on `var r = (IManager) managerClass;` and I don't understand how to cast that object to be of type IManager.

EDIT:  I have fixed the above code with appropriate variable names to remove confusion.

Comment: Why do you use typeof(IMyManager).IsAssignableFrom(t)) but then cast to IManager?  In one case  you use IMyManager and in the other IManager.

Comment: @Derek that was a typo, I have fixed it.

Comment: Also report is a type.  It is not an IManager, it is the type that implements IManager.  So you should be doing a List<Type>?

Comment: Adding to what Derek said, `report` is a `System.Type` that cannot be type-casted as IManager. It is not a class instance as you are assuming it to be.

Comment: @Abhinav is there a way for me to accomplish that?  By maybe creating it as an instance first?  If so how would that work?

Comment: @Abhinav I figured out the answer, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the place where you're doing the `var r = (IManager) report` the report is still a `Type` object. You will need to instantiate that type. You can do this using [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) but you might also want to make some assertions about the constructor for that type first (e.g. require a parameterless constructor) and also check that it's a concrete class type (i.e. not abstract).

Comment: Lets say that I have TeamManager and PlayerManager and they both have the interface IManager.  Interface inforces a property called Name.  How would I instantiate that and be able to call Name property to print out?  Lets assume that Name is instantiated upon creation.  I am also assuming here that I find both objects using my code posted in question.

Comment: @Bagzli - That's great news! Perhaps you can share your code as an edit or an answer?